# Прегруженная функция-член не найдена

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте!

Пишу программу в VS 2010 на C++. Помогите, пожалуйста, ошибку, которая возникла из-за перегруженности функции. Где перегружается, я знаю, но почему, не пойму.
Ведь самое интересно в том, что когда в классе наводишь мышку на его описание, оно выводит данный код, а при его использование пишите переопределению со всеми вытекающими. Задачи программы состоит в вычислении и нахождении координат точки на координатной плоскости. Ошибка возникла при написании функции увеличения.

Программа состоит из 3 файлов.

usePixel.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Point.h"
#include "Pixel.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << Pixel::GetK() << endl;
    {
    Pixel a(10,20,Pixel::red);
    cout<<"Pixel a: "; a.Print(); cout << endl;

    cout << Pixel::GetK() << endl;

    Pixel b (Point(30,40), Pixel::blue);
    cout<<"Pixel b: "; b.Print(); cout << endl;

    cout << Pixel::GetK() << endl;

//  b.SetColor(Pixel::green);
    b.Move(10,20);
    cout<<"Pixel b: "; b.Print(); cout << endl;

    cout << "Dist = " << a.Dist(b) << endl;
    cout << "Color of Pixel b= " << b.GetColor() << endl;

    Pixel c = a;
    cout<<"Pixel c: "; c.Print(); cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    }

    cout << Pixel::GetK() << endl;
}
```

Pixel.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Pixel.h"

using namespace std;

int Pixel::k = 0;

Pixel::Pixel(int x, int y, const  Color &clr)
: p(x,y), c(clr)
{ ++k; }

Pixel::Pixel(const Point &pt, const  Color &clr)
: p(pt), c(clr)
{ ++k; }

 //Ошибка тут начинается
Pixel::Pixel(const Point &px)
: p(px.p), c(px.c)
{ ++k; }
//Тут заканчивается

Pixel::~Pixel()
{  -- k;}

//==========================================

const Pixel::Color & Pixel::GetColor()const
{
    return c;
}
/*
void Pixel::SetColor(const Color &clr)
{
    //c= clr;
}
*/
void Pixel::Move (int delta_x, int delta_y)
{
    p.Move(delta_x, delta_y);
}

double Pixel::Dist(const Pixel &px)const
{
    return p.Dist(px.p);
}

void Pixel::Print()const
{
    p.Print();
    cout << c;
}
```

Pixel.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "point.h"

class Pixel
{
public:
    enum Color{black, blue, green, red = 4, yellow = 14, white};
    Pixel(int = 0, int = 0, const  Color& = black);
    Pixel(const Point &, const  Color& = black);
    Pixel(const Pixel &);
    ~Pixel();

    const Color & GetColor()const;
    //void SetColor(const Color &);

    void Move (int delta_x, int delta_y);
    double Dist(const Pixel &)const;

    void Print()const;

    static int GetK() { return k+n; }

private:
    Point p;
    const Color c;
    static int k;
    static const int n = 100;
};
```

Ошибка VS 2010:

```
1>------ Построение начато: проект: Pixel, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Построение начато 15.02.2012 18:41:27.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Обращение к "Debug\Pixel.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Pixel.cpp
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pixel\pixel\pixel.cpp(18): error C2511: Pixel::Pixel(const Point &): перегруженная функция-член не найдена в "Pixel"
1>          c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pixel\pixel\pixel.h(7): см. объявление "Pixel"
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\pixel\pixel\pixel.cpp(52): fatal error C1004: непредвиденное обнаружение конца файла
1>
1>СБОЙ построения.
```

Благодарю!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас функция обьявлена как

```
Pixel(const Pixel &);
```

а определена как

```
Pixel::Pixel(const Point &px)
```

`Pixel` и `Point` - разные классы.

Comment: Спасибо! Я правда уже сам нашёл. Вопрос закрыт, ответ найден.